# Error installing SymbolicC++ on unix

Tags: installation, symbolicc++

I downloaded SymbolicC++ from:

http://issc.uj.ac.za/symbolic/sources/SymbolicC++3-3.35-ac.tar.gz

Then I went into the folder and did:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

But when I typed in "make", it came back with the following error:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:1307:9: error: no matching member function for call to
      'assign'
        assign(__x.__begin_, __x.__end_);
        ^~~~~~
```